# Visual Studio 2017 - python tool

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I reinstalled Python environment on my PC. But in `Visual Studio Installer` I still see, that `Python` is installed. So I reinstall it on my VS2017 too.

My question is, Does `Visual Studio` have their own instance of `Python` installed? If I uninstall `Python` from my PC, will the Python on `VS` still be running? I'm asking this because when I reinstalled Python in `VS` I wasn't able to use python from my `cmd` (to install packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install packages from within VisualStudio ... open the PythonEnvironments - Tab (View/OtherWindows/PythonEnvironments) - for me it is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>)

To check which python is used by VS, go to the PythonEnvironments - it displays it for you:

[image: Anaconda]

[image: Python3.6]

And if you change **Overview** to **Packages (PyPI)** you can install new packages for *that* environment:

[image: Install stuff]

HTH

[RedCircles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/377931) overtaking SO :P

Comment: I used `PowerShell`. I had an error, so i needed to add `--user` permission. something like: `pip install --user package`. Works, thanks